# State of bool failing to prevent function from repeating

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, boolean, conditional-statements

Having trouble tracking this down for some reason, it should be simple but I'm missing something. In `PreCountdownTimer()` I'm getting two bool properties from `GameManager.cs` assigning them to `_userActive` and `_preCountdownActive` and then looking for changes in **`Update()`**. When `_userActive = false && _preCountdownActive = false` it kicks off **`StartPreCountTimer()`** and sets `_preCountdownActive` to true.

Now once this happens **`Update()`** should no longer be able to call **`StartPreCountTimer()`** as per the conditional statement...but it still does. This is resulting in my timer getting called over and over again, every frame, thus preventing it from being able to countdown. What do I have wrong here that is preventing the `_preCountdownActive` bool from stopping **`Update`** from firing **`StartPreCountTimer()`**?

**`PreCountdownTimer.cs`**

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class PreCountdownTimer : MonoBehaviour {

    public bool ShowRestartDialog { get; set; }
    private IEnumerator counter;
    private bool _startPrecount;
    private float _preCountdownInterval;
    private bool _preCountdownActive = false;
    private bool _userActive = false;
    private float _timerLength;

    void Start()
    {
        _timerLength = GameManager.Instance.PreCountdownLength;
    }

   void Update()
    {
        _userActive = GameManager.Instance.UserActive;

        if (!_userActive && !_preCountdownActive)
            StartPreCountTimer(_timerLength);
        else if (_userActive && _preCountdownActive)
            StopPreCountTimer();

        Debug.Log("The state of preCountdownActive is: " + _preCountdownActive);
    }

    void StartPreCountTimer(float length)
    {
        _preCountdownActive = true;
        counter = RunTimer(length);
        StartCoroutine(counter);   
    }

    void StopPreCountTimer()
    {
        _preCountdownActive = false;
        StopCoroutine(counter);
    }

    IEnumerator RunTimer(float seconds)
    {
        float s = seconds;
        while (s > 0)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(_preCountdownInterval);
            s -= _preCountdownInterval;
            Debug.Log("PreCount: " + s);
        }

        if (s == 0)
        {
            _preCountdownActive = false;
            ShowRestartDialog = true;
        }

    }
}
```

**`GameManager.cs`**

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static GameManager Instance = null; // create singleton

    public Object introScene;

    public bool UserActive { get; set; }
    public bool OnIntroScreen { get; set; }

    public GameObject preCountdownTimerPrefab;
    private GameObject _preCountdownTimerInstance;
    public float PreCountdownLength { get; protected set; }
    public float PreCountdownInterval { get; protected set; }

    private float _checkMousePositionTimingInterval = 1.0f;
    private Vector3 _currentMousePosition;
    private Vector3 _prevMousePosition;
    private Scene _currentScene;

    void Awake()
    {
        if (Instance == null)
            Instance = this;
        else if (Instance != null)
            Destroy(gameObject);

        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }

    void OnEnable()
    {
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded += OnSceneLoaded;
    }

    void OnSceneLoaded(Scene scene, LoadSceneMode mode)
    {
        _currentScene = scene;
    }

    void Start()
    {
        PreCountdownLength = 5.0f;
        PreCountdownInterval = 1.0f;

        OnIntroScreen = true;
        UserActive = false;

        _prevMousePosition = Input.mousePosition;

        InvokeRepeating("LastMousePosition", 0, _checkMousePositionTimingInterval); 
    }

    void Update()
    {
        _currentMousePosition = Input.mousePosition;

        if (_currentScene.name != introScene.name)
        {
            OnIntroScreen = false;
            if (_currentMousePosition != _prevMousePosition)
                UserActive = true;
            else
                UserActive = false;       
        }
        else if (_currentScene.name == introScene.name)
            OnIntroScreen = true;

        if (!UserActive && !OnIntroScreen)
            if (_preCountdownTimerInstance == null)
                _preCountdownTimerInstance = Instantiate(preCountdownTimerPrefab);
        else if (UserActive)
            if (_preCountdownTimerInstance != null)
                Destroy(_preCountdownTimerInstance);
    }

    void LastMousePosition()
    {
        _prevMousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the value of `GameManager.Instance.UserActive` ever change? If not, then that's rather confusing since I'm not seeing how your code could enter both if statements repeatedly...

Comment: yes the value of GameManager.Instance.UserActive changes depending on mouse movement. When the user is idle it is false and when active it is true.

Comment: Please add a Debug.Log in Update for your userActive field.

Comment: @hoodaticus I have`Debug.Log("The state of _userActive is: " + _userActive);` and
        `Debug.Log("The state of _preCountdownActive is: " + _preCountdownActive);`. Everything was registering as it should based on mouse movement. When there is no user activity `_userActive` is false and `_preCountdownActive` is true. When there is user activity `_userActive` is true and `_preCountdownActive` is false. This is weirdness.

Comment: @greyBow - what have you done to anger the gods, and do you have any animals to sacrifice for their appeasement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by directly accessing the properties rather than saving the property values to local variables and accessing the local variables. Hopefully this is a proper way to do it?

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class PreCountdownTimer : MonoBehaviour {

    private IEnumerator counter;

   void Update()
    {
        if (!GameManager.Instance.UserActive && !GameManager.Instance.PreCountdownActive)
            StartPreCountTimer(GameManager.Instance.PreCountdownLength);
        else if (GameManager.Instance.UserActive && GameManager.Instance.PreCountdownActive)
            StopPreCountTimer();
    }

    void StartPreCountTimer(float length)
    {
        GameManager.Instance.PreCountdownActive = true;
        counter = RunTimer(length);
        StartCoroutine(counter);   
    }

    void StopPreCountTimer()
    {
        GameManager.Instance.PreCountdownActive = false;
        StopCoroutine(counter);
    }

    IEnumerator RunTimer(float seconds)
    {
        float s = seconds;
        while (s > 0)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(GameManager.Instance.PreCountdownInterval);
            s -= GameManager.Instance.PreCountdownInterval;
            Debug.Log("PreCount: " + s);
        }

        if (s == 0)
        {
            GameManager.Instance.PreCountdownActive = false;
        }
    }
}
```